# Problem with compilations projects in x86 and x64

Tags: c#, 64-bit, x86, compilation, 32bit-64bit

I work with the application that has to be run in 64 bit Windows and I use OCX control that should be run in 32 bit emulation mode. I can embed this control in Windows Forms Control Library and then add reference to this library to main application in order to set another emulation mode for this control and another for whole application, but it generate another problem. In this case I get an error "Exception of type InvalidActiveXStateException was thrown". I tried to use this Windows Forms Control Library with the project that was also run in x86 and everything was ok.

Do you know in which way I can run application which contains two or more projects that one project would be run in x86 and one in x64? (Right know when each project is in another mode it can't find some assemblies)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't mix 32 and 64 bit code in the same process.  If you absolutely must run this 32 bit control from a 64 bit app then you'd need to do it as an out of process server.  Whilst this is probably feasible I don't believe it to be trivial.

Anyway, you may very well not need to do this.  Since 64 bit Windows runs 32 bit apps you can make sure that your app targets **x86** instead of **AnyCPU** and then it will run on 64 bit Windows.

Comment: +1 This is indeed impossible. Remember that 32-bit applications on 64-bit versions of Windows run under the dedicated Windows on Windows (WOW64) subsystem. You can't call 64-bit code from a 32-bit process. [This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/10/20/9006720.aspx) provides a more comprehensive explanation. The proposed workaround sounds acceptable to me, absent simply recompiling the OCX in 64-bit.

Comment: I tried to set x86 for Windows Forms Control Library where is embed OCX and x64 for another project, which recall Windows Forms Control and it doesn't work. There is no formal error, but this OCX control is MapPoint Control, which is no loaded, so I have an empty win form instead win form with map point control. I also tried in opposite way - set in both project x86, but in this situation first project compile with error (can't find assembly)

Comment: @user512150: Right, that's the point. You're trying to run code from one project set to x86 inside of another project compiled for x64. As the answer and my comment indicate, that's not possible. The platforms for both projects need to *match*. If you can't change the OCX to 64-bit (x64), you need to change the other projects to 32-bit (x86) so that they match it.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I'm not very sure if this is what you're looking for, but you can create two projects for any of your current projects.</strike>

Source code lives in one of the pairs and so on, and the X64 or X86 adds all files using Visual Studio symbolic links.

Then, you don't need to maintain duplicate code and you'll only need to configure one project for X86, and the counterpart for X64 and so on.

Symbolic links are created when you try to add an existing item, and you press in the arrow and you choose "add link".

I found that this is not a solution for you (and almost wrong). Thanks to commenters.

Comment: Not what he's looking for. There's absolutely no reason to create two separate projects when you have conditional compilation. Additionally, you miss the primary issue: 64-bit mode applications cannot run 32-bit code in the same process.

Comment: Well there's a reason for having two separate projects: if you use symlinks, it's one project, mirrored in another one for compilation only. You're avoding the need of using a lot of conditional compilation directives everywhere (cleaner code). If you know you need to compile in both kinds of CPU and it'll be always be this way, why not? About the second fact, you're right, my solution doesn't solve the process requirements for 64bit ones.

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong with telling Visual Studio to compile your original project either for x86 or x64. Two separate projects just seems like unnecessary work when this functionality is built-in. [See here](http://thingsthatshouldbeeasy.blogspot.com/2009/08/anycpu-x86-x64-whats-difference.html) for more details on platform targeting.

Comment: I know I know, my answer is wrong. I wrongly understood the problem. Thank you.

Comment: @Matias: Not *wrong*, so much as what I would consider to be an unnecessary amount of work. And hey, the goal is to learn something. If that's a feature of VS that you didn't know about before, you might have saved yourself a considerable amount of time in the future. (There's nothing wrong with leaving the answer here, but you *can* delete it using one of the links at the bottom if you want to.)

Comment: I know such feature, man! haha, I just thought a bad solution, everyones can make mistakes, that's all. I prefer to show I can have mistakes than hidding them, that's all. I know platform targeting and I've used it in a couple of projects. And obviosuly, you're right, we're not here for answering only but learning every day, but it's not the case, I just did an unnecessary, wrong or any thing you'd want to call my answer :)